# How to have the number and the caption of a figure in Word showing in one line?

Tags: microsoft-word

Using APA style, I have the figure number and the figure caption in two different lines.
For example

[image]

When I use `Insert Table of Figure` on the `References` tab, I get a table that only captures the figure number. For example, it shows as:

Figure 2.............15

What I want to achieve is
Figure 2: Framework for Sequential Exploratory Mixed Methods.....15

[15 is the page number]
I also have all my tables and Appendix in the double-line format. I need to get the same results for them too.

How to achieve this in Microsoft Word?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you have the figure number and the figure caption in two different lines with an end-of-paragraph in-between, you could use a soft end-of-line, meaning Shift+Enter, to separate the lines. This should show up as one line in the table.